# Retrieving check-boxes to see if it is checked or not laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a check-box in my product form, by default the check-box is not checked, and is set to 0. if the check-box is checked, it will insert a 1 into database to let it know the product will be featured in the front page.

The problem I'm having is when I go edit the product, the check-box is not checked, even though there is a 1 in database. I have tried many solutions, but cant come up with a right one that will work.

Here is my function:

```html
public function addPostProduct(ProductRequest $request) {

        // Check if checkbox is checked or not for featured product
        $featured = Input::has('featured') ? true : false;

        // Create the product in DB
        $product = Product::create([
            'product_name' => $request->input('product_name'),
            'price' => $request->input('price'),
            'cat_id' => $request->input('cat_id'),
            'featured' => $featured
        ]);

        // Save the product into the Database.
        $product->save();

        // Flash a success message
        flash()->success('Success', 'Product created successfully!');

        // Redirect back to Show all products page.
        return redirect()->route('admin.product.show');
    }
```

Here is my add form ( Just showing the check-box):

```html
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Fetaured Product</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="featured" value="1">
</div>
```

here is my edit form (just showing the check-box):

```html
 <div class="form-group">
      <label>Fetaured Product</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="featured" value="1">
</div>
```

And my table structure:

```html
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('product_name');
            $table->decimal('price', 10, 2);
            $table->integer('cat_id');
            $table->integer('featured')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Checkboxes don’t magically check themselves, just because of a value in your database. You need to output the `checked` attribute if you want it to be checked by default.

Comment: so something like this: **<input type="checkbox" name="featured" value="1" {{ $product->featured === 1 ? "checked=checked" : "" }}>**

Comment: Yes, that is a pretty common way of doing this. (Although a simple `checked` is enough, at least in HTML5, since this is a [boolean attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute).)

Comment: ya, but that doesn't work, as soon as I go edit it, and for example "unchecke it", and submit the form, it still stays checked

Comment: Well then most likely your `$product->featured` variable still contains 1.

Comment: I got it working, check the answer I put up

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my updateProduct function as well I guess.

```html
 public function updateProduct($id, ProductEditRequest $request) {

        // Check if checkbox is checked or not for featured product
        $featured = Input::has('featured') ? true : false;

        $product = Product::where('id', '=', $id);

        // Update your cart
        $product->update(array(
            'product_name' => $request->input('product_name'),
            'price'   => $request->input('price'),
            'cat_id'    => $request->input('cat_id'),
            'featured'     => $featured
        ));


        // Find the Products ID from URL in route
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

        // Update the product with all the validation rules
        $product->update($request->all());

        // Flash a success message
        flash()->success('Success', 'Product updated successfully!');

        // Redirect back to Show all categories page.
        return redirect()->route('admin.product.show');
    }
```

And my edit form check-box with this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
          <label>Fetaured Product</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="featured" value="1" {{ $product->featured === 1 ? "checked=checked" : "" }}>
</div>
```